# can form validation be over crossed in html5?

Tags: html

Is it possible to overcome the form validation errors in html5 by deleting the code while inspecting element? For example, if I set a textarea as required="true", can someone delete the "required" sentence of code by opening inspect element and hence can overcome this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that's how the web works. Client-side validation is just a convenience for the user—it cannot replace server-side validation.

Comment: thanks guys! I will go ahead with php validation then.

Comment: I would honestly implement both for a better user experience ;) At least you have to tell the user what went wrong if he made mistakes while submitting a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The rule

... says that every client side validation can be skipped! It doesn't matter if it is native HTML5 validation or some kind of javascript validation.

#### The solution

... is, to implement a bulletproof server side validation!

#### Always remember

... that you don't need a browser to send HTTP-requests to your server. (*No Browser = No client side validation.*)

... that you cannot rely on browser. Each browser has a different implementation of HTML5 (if indeed it's implemented). So the form validation isn't always the same.